# How to specify the unique property in loopback4 (aka. loopback-next) for model definition?

Tags: properties, model, unique

There is way to define unique property by using `{index: {unique: true}}` in loopback3, but for loopback4, only supported very limited options in `@property()`, and no way to define unique field in doc. Does any one have experience to solve this issue?